# How to set an event listener to detect changes in iframe that streams content using Selenium with Python

Tags: python, selenium, web, iframe, streaming

I have an iframe that streams content, and I want to set an event listener. I've searched quite a bit, but haven't been able to find an answer.
I currently just check for new content at time intervals, but surely there's a better way.